# Javascript - React destructuring array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I am trying to learn ReactJS and I'm having some trouble understanding the destructuring occurring in the following snippet:

```
const IngredientsList = ({ list }) =>  
    React.createElement('ul', null,
      list.map((ingredient, i) =>
        React.createElement('li', {key: i}, ingredient))

const Ingredients = React.createFactory(IngredientsList)
const list = [
     "1 lb Salmon",
     "1 cup Pine Nuts",
     "2 cups Butter Lettuce",
 ]
```

This should be equivalent to:

```
 const IngredientsList = props =>
  ....
     props.list.map(...)
```

I thought only on an object such a destructuring is available. Can you shed some light how the two of above are equivalent? Is it something specific to react?

Comment: `props` _is_ an object. `list` is an array passed down to the component in `props`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's format your example and add one extra line to show how to use it:

```
const IngredientsList = ({list}) => {
  return React.createElement("ul", null, list.map((ingredient, i) => {
    return React.createElement("li", {key: i}, ingredient)
  }))
}

const Ingredients = React.createFactory(IngredientsList)
const list = [
  "1 lb Salmon",
  "1 cup Pine Nuts",
  "2 cups Butter Lettuce",
]

// usage:
Ingredients({list})
```

As you can see, what you pass to `Ingredients` is the `props` *Object*. The same object can be destructured as the argument of the `IngedientsList` function.

You can find in [this explanation](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/d7bce729f38730399d28#the-solution) another example of using `React.createFactory`, again: passing an object which contains the props.